# Getting elements by type in malformed HTML

Tags: java, html-parsing

What's the easiest way in Java to retrieve all elements with a certain type in a malformed HTML page?  So I want to do something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Read in an HTML file from disk
    // Retrieve all INPUT elements regardless of whether the HTML is well-formed
    // Loop through all elements and retrieve their ids if they exist for the element
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[HtmlCleaner](http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/) is arguably one of the best HTML parsers out there when it comes to dealing with (somewhat) malformed HTML.

Documentation is [here](http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/javause.php) with some code samples; you're basically looking for `getElementsByName()` method.

Take a look at [Comparison of Java HTML parsers](http://www.benmccann.com/dev-blog/java-html-parsing-library-comparison/) if you're considering other libraries.

Answer (score 1):

I've had success using [tagsoup](http://home.ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/). Heres a short description from their home page:

> This is the home page of TagSoup, a SAX-compliant parser written in Java that, instead of parsing well-formed or valid XML, parses HTML as it is found in the wild: poor, nasty and brutish, though quite often far from short. TagSoup is designed for people who have to process this stuff using some semblance of a rational application design. By providing a SAX interface, it allows standard XML tools to be applied to even the worst HTML. TagSoup also includes a command-line processor that reads HTML files and can generate either clean HTML or well-formed XML that is a close approximation to XHTML.

Answer (score 0):

Check [Jtidy](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/).

> JTidy is a Java port of HTML Tidy, a
>   HTML syntax checker and pretty
>   printer. Like its non-Java cousin,
>   JTidy can be used as a tool for
>   cleaning up malformed and faulty HTML.
>   In addition, JTidy provides a DOM
>   interface to the document that is
>   being processed, which effectively
>   makes you able to use JTidy as a DOM
>   parser for real-world HTML.